# WebpackDevMiddleware in ASP.NET Core app in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: c#, asp.net, npm, webpack, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to use `WebpackDevMiddleware` with `HotModuleReplacement` in an ASP.NET Core app.  I followed the following guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa-services in setting up webpack to work with ASP.NET.

When I deploy my ASP.NET Core app via Service Fabric, the following error is thrown:

> Call to Node module failed with error: Webpack dev middleware failed
>   because of an error while loading 'aspnet-webpack'....

I noticed that inside my `wwwroot/` folder, I have no `node_modules`, dependencies, etc... and so this error seems to make sense.  The ASP.NET core app does not seem to have access to the `aspnet-webpack` node module.  Additionally, in other projects' `wwwroot` folders there appears to be a `dependencies` folder visible in Visual Studio, while in mine there is no such folder.

I'm wondering how I can give the ASP.NET core app access to the modules it needs?

Comment: This was useful for me: https://mattfrear.com/2017/09/26/run-a-service-fabric-solution-locally-without-deploying-to-service-fabric/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that ServiceFabric does not support Hot Module Replacement at this time.

To get around this I added the following:

```
#if DEBUG
app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
{
    HotModuleReplacement = true
});
#endif
```

So that you only use HMR when in debug mode and when you publish to local/production cluster HMR is not used.